# design fields which links to a record from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm defining a data structure for airline routing.

The expected usage will be like that

```
Route.find(1).from_airport # NRT
Route.find(1).to_airport # KIX
Route.find(2).from_airport # NRT
Route.find(2).to_airport # TPE
```

However, I don't want to define a string value in from_airport field or to_airport field.

The airport data shouls be maintained in airports table.

How could I define it within Ruby on Rails?

Does it belongs to has_one logic on Route table and there is no belongs_to logic for airport.

## Model: Route (In my thought)

```
has_one :from_airport, foreign_key: "id??", class_name: "Route"
has_one :to_airport, foreign_key: "id??", class_name: "Route"
```

## Airports table

```
id:1 name: NRT, city: TOKYO, country: JAPAN
id:2 name: KIX, city: OSAKA, country: JAPAN
```

## Routes table

```
from_airport:  # it should NOT be a string, it should refers to a record in Airports table eg: airport (id:1)
to_airport:  # it should NOT be a string, it should refers to a record in Airports table eg: airport (id:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
# routes.rb
belongs_to :from_airport, foreign_key: :from_airport_id, class_name: "Airport", primary_key: :id
belongs_to :to_airport, foreign_key: :to_airport_id, class_name: "Airport", primary_key: :id
```